# Google Plus - share map or positions

Tags: android, google-maps, google-plus

I'm getting familiar with Plus API, I have successfully posted string on my google plus via:

```
 Intent intent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
                            .setType("text/plain")
                            .setText("Hi all")
                            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://plus.google.com"))
                            .getIntent();

        startActivityForResult(intent, PLUS_INTENT_RESULT);
```

But I wasn't able to find a way to post a `GoogleMap` or locations, or mark a postition on map. But I can't add a map to a web google plus:

[image: no add map]]

Ass you can see, there's no add map or location

there is only `Link` possibility but I want to display map like in Hangouts

[image]]

Could you give me some hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you are using utilizes the Google Plus framework API. There is no way you can modify them in order to get the Maps or location to be shared.

But yes, as you mentioned there are other long routes that you can take in order to share user's location or even maps.

Comment: I didn't find anything related to my problem. I was wandering about generating link from GoogleMap in android an send it to GooglePlus, but I did't find anything how to retrieve web link from GoogleMap in android